# Android NDK Integration: Error: Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.Application

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2) tutorial and the Teapot example by google.

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "..."
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

}


android.buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
    }
}

}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

And I get the following error while trying to sync:

```
    Error:Unable to find method 
'com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.<init>       
    (Lorg/gradle/api/Project;Lcom/android/builder/core/AndroidBuilder;
        Landroid/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder;
     Lcom/android/build/gradle/AndroidConfig;Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/
 SdkHandler;Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/DependencyManager;Lorg/gradle/tooling/
    provider/model/ToolingModelBuilderRegistry;)V'.
```

I tried playing with the dependecies including removing them completely, restarting Android studio but I'm lost as it seems to be ok.

My versions:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-rc3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, it happened because I had 2 classpaths.

Once I removed the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'`

It worked.

Comment: it solves your issue, but to be more accurate, you can keep these two classpaths if you need to use the gradle stable plugin and the experimental one at the same time. In that case you have to use version that matches such as `2.1.0-alpha5` for the gradle plugin, and `0.7.0-alpha5` for the gradle-experimental one.